# Can I scaffold with EF Core and get SQL Server Date as DateOnly and not as Datetime?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, scaffold

I am having this problem while running `scaffold-dbcontext`, it is representing SQL Server `date` columns as `datetime`.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Not yet. [Support for DateOnly and TimeOnly](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24507) is expected in EF Core 7. You can use custom converters to map `date` to  `DateOnly` properties

Comment: `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` are not yet supported naturally in EF Core/ADO.NET, so probably that's why EF Core scaffolding is not using it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed. But OP wants scaffolding (reverse engineering,  model type property is generated, out of control), so value converters are not an option

Comment: The change can be made afterwards. There's no other option right now

Comment: You can use the T4 templates in EF Core 7 to fo this.